# Can Apache Web server Respond to SMTP/IMAP/POP3 requests?

Tags: apache-httpd, smtp, imap

I want to know what functions are provided by the Apache 2.4.9 Web server on Fedora 20. I understand that Apache responds to HTTP request only. I believe that SMTP and POP3 protocols don't use HTTP. Is this correct?

Can Apache respond to protocols other than HTTP? Can we have more than one Apache process running on a single IP address that will respond to HTTP requests as well as mail requests?

Answer (score 2):

Although I suppose you could configure Apache to listen on the relevant ports for other services, and you could conceivably write a new module to allow you to have it respond to other services such as SMTP, the question would be... why would you want to? (reinventing the wheel and all that)

You could setup other services for handling SMTP, etc., running on the same system without trying to adapt Apache for a use it is not originally intended for.

You may want to start over, what is your end goal, what are you trying to accomplish? If the Fedora box needs to be able to handle SMTP connections to/from it, you could configure sendmail for that need. If you also need it to be a mail server (so that the mailboxes reside on it) then you could do that as well (been a while since I have setup a *nix box as a mail server, so I will refrain on providing suggestions on the best applications).

Comment: JFTR there exists multiple modules for handling different protocols such as POP3 and SMTP - see http://httpd.apache.org/modules/ for some examples